# Reorder dataframes in a list in r:

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames: my_list which contains 18 dataframes

```
> names(my_list)
 [1] "UG 100-12" "UG 100-15" "UG 100-9"  "UG 108-12" "UG 108-15" "UG 108-9"  "UG 116-12" "UG 116-15"
 [9] "UG 116-9"  "UG 124-12" "UG 124-15" "UG 124-9"  "UG 84-12"  "UG 84-15"  "UG 84-9"   "UG 92-12" 
[17] "UG 92-15"  "UG 92-9"
```

I want to reorder the list based on a vector of the names in the correct order:

```
df <- c("UG 84-9", "UG 84-12", "UG 84-15", "UG 92-9", "UG 92-12", "UG 92-15", "UG 100-9", 
        "UG 100-12", "UG 100-15", "UG 108-9", "UG 108-12", "UG 108-15", "UG 116-9", "UG 116-12", 
        "UG 116-15", "UG 124-9", "UG 124-12", "UG 124-15")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: do you mean `mylist[df]` ?

Comment: @rawr I am not sure I understand your question. `my_list` is a list containing 18 dataframes. i want to reorder these dataframes, in the order described by the column `df`

Comment: so you have a list of objects, `mylist <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)` and a vector of desired order `df <- c('c', 'a', 'b')` and you want to re-order `mylist`? `mylist[df]` does that. or do you mean you want to order the rows and/or columns of _each_ data frame in your list?

Comment: @rawr Oh that makes perfect sense, sorry for the confusion! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
my_ordered_list <- mylist[sort(names(mylist))]
```